# Raspbian Kernel and initramfs

Tags: raspbian, boot, raspbian-jessie

I'm trying to switch my Raspberry Pi 2 to the raspbian kernel rather than the one from raspberry pi foundation (found in `raspberrypi-bootloader` package).

I installed the `linux-image-rpi2-rpfv` package, which gave me the appropriate files in /boot:

```
/boot/System.map-4.4.0-1-rpi2
/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1-rpi2
/boot/config-4.4.0-1-rpi2
```

During installation an initrd file was generated for this kernel:

```
/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1-rpi2
```

I updated my config.txt to point to the new initrd:

```
[...]
initramfs initrd.img-4.4.0-1-rpi2
[...]
```

And the boot worked fine, but booted the old kernel (kernel7.img, 4.4.11-v7+), since that is still the default.
So I set the kernel parameter in config.txt to point to the new kernel:

```
[...]
kernel=vmlinuz-4.4.0-1-rpi2
initramfs initrd.img-4.4.0-1-rpi2
[...]
```

And I get stuck with the fullscreen rainbow square indicating a boot issue.

I've tried regenerating the initrd file with `update-initramfs -u` but since the default kernel boots fine I doubt that's where the issue is.

This is the contents of my cmdline.txt:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 elevator=deadline root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes consoleblank=0 rootwait fastboot noswap
```

This is the full config.txt that fails:

```
gpu_mem=512
force_turbo=1
avoid_pwm_pll=1
v3d_freq=400
disable_overscan=1
kernel=vmlinuz-4.4.0-1-rpi2
initramfs initrd.img-4.4.0-1-rpi2
framebuffer_depth=32
framebuffer_ignore_alpha=1
framebuffer_swap=0
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

Any hints on how to actually boot the kernel from the `linux-image-rpi2-rpfv` package?

Answer (score 2):

## Use `ramfsfile` Instead

This confused me at first too, but `initramfs` is not the right key to specify just the `initramfs` file.

> ### ramfsfile
>
> Optional filename on the boot partition of a ramfs to load. More information is available [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=10532).
>
> ### ramfsaddr
>
> The memory address into which the ramfsfile should be loaded.
>
> ### initramfs
>
> This specifies both the ramfs filename and the memory address to load it at; it performs the actions of both ramfsfile and ramfsaddr in one parameter. Example values are: initramfs initramf.gz 0x00800000. NOTE: This option uses different syntax to all the other options; you should not use a = character here.

[Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md)