# Which file in /boot is the initial RAM disk?

Tags: raspbian, kernel, qemu, init

In order to emulate a Pi in the Qemu emulator, I will need to identify which (if any) of the files in /boot is the RAM disk, and which is the appropriate kernel.

Booting Raspbian however, there is no file called initrd.gz or similar.

How can I determine which file is the initrd, and which is the appropriate kernel?

Comment: There is NO RAM disk!

Comment: Do you mean the swap file?  Check dphys-swapfile in /etc for location and info if you do.

Comment: Maybe some research would help... [this](https://blog.agchapman.com/using-qemu-to-emulate-a-raspberry-pi/), and [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49980/raspbian-kernel-and-initramfs)

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi OS does not use an Init RAM Disk. If you need one you have to create it by yourself. In addition to the ramdisk you have to add some settings in `/boot/config.txt`. I have an example to load storage drivers on an early stage. You may have a look at [Easy backups and snapshots of a running system with LVM](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85959/79866). To get an idea just only look at the section **Prepare the installation with LVM drivers**.